# In an SRGS grammar, how do I specify that a phrase be replaced by a word

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, srgs

I’m using .NET System.Speech to write a simple app to transcribe audio files. All is well except it constantly outputs “dot net” when, of course I want it to output “.NET”.

So, is there a way to write an SRGS rule that does this?

**Also** can someone with enough reputation create the tag “SRGS” please.

Answer (score 1):

In SRGS, without a semantic component, you a recognizing tokens (e.g. words).  A dot (ie .) is not a valid character for a token.  If you are using SISR, you can correct the text within the rule.

You could use dotnet as a token with suitable pronunciation rules, but depending on the recognition engine, may still see dot net as a valid recognition.

I recommend performing a post recognition semantic processing step to convert instances of "dot net" to ".NET" This allows you to fix other similar or contextual problems with the content.

Comment: I had half expected that I would need to do string substitution. Thank you for the confirmation, save me a bunch of time.